# Realm in swift: Access objects from list inside a class

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Im trying to access the objects from a list created in a class. How can i do this?

**Function where i want to access the objects from selectedInfo:**

```
func loadContactInfo() {
        
   let selectedInfo = selectedContact?.info
        
}
```

```
class InfoViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    var selectedContact: Contact? {
        didSet {
            loadContactInfo()
        }
    }
```

```
class Contact : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    let info = List<ContactInfo>()
}
```

```
class ContactInfo : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var phone : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var birthday : String = ""
    var parentContact = LinkingObjects(fromType: Contact.self, property: "info")
}
```

I want to access the properties of ContactInfo from the list inside Contact.

Comment: "I want to access the properties of ContactInfo from the list inside Contact." Okay, ***which one?*** Since it's a list, there could be many `ContactInfo`s in a `Contact`.

Comment: The "selectedContact" variable is of type Contact, and what im basically doing is a simple contact app in which the user fills the properties from ContactInfo, and when they are filled, a new "Contact" is made and i want to access its properties.

Comment: It sounds like each contact only has one `ContactInfo`, not a list of them? Change `let info = List<ContactInfo>()` to `@objc dynamic var info: ContactInfo?` then.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks! @Sweeper. I'll post and update if it worked

Comment: It worked! Thanks @Sweeper